# Python pip проблема с соединением (Retrying)

Tags: python, pip, connection

Скорее всего таких вопросов куча, так что тыкните носом

Windows 10

После обычной установке `python` и `pip` (любой версии и разрядности) при попытке установить любой модуль возникают такие предупреждения и ошибки (на примере `click`):

```
>>> pip install click

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1ad239a340>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/click/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1ad3296040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/click/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1ad3296100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/click/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1ad32960d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/click/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1ad327e9d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/click/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement click (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for click
```

## НО

**При использовании `python` и `pip`, ставящихся при установкие `Anaconda`, все срабатывает нормально**

Как решить проблему?

Гуглить пробовал - видимо не умею, ничего, кроме прямого скачивания архивов библиотек и установки с помощью `python setup.py install` ничего не нашел

P.S. Мне не получится использовать `python` и `pip`, устанавливающиеся анакондой, нужен просто `python`

Comment: https://github.com/platformio/platformio-vscode-ide/issues/415

Comment: @dIm0n ну я подобное уже видел, антивирус не мешает, другого там ничего особо тоже не нашел

Comment: Стоит привести в вопросе все решения, которые вы пробовали

Comment: @dIm0n Я пока не особо представляю, куда копнуть можно. Proxy/VPN не пользуюсь, антивирус пробовал отключать

Comment: @dIm0n, наконец получилось! Сейчас напишу, что помогло мне

Comment: Ничего не помогает, пробовал куча разных версий пайтон но есть подозрения на интернет так как недавно поменял роутер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло удаление из реестра (Win+R `regedit`) в директории `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` ключа `ProxyEnabled` и переустановка `Python`